# How to get waypoints latitude longitude between two places of google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, latitude-longitude

I would like to retrieve the latitudes and longitudes( waypoints) between two points.

For example the waypoints between PIKINE and GUEDIAWAYE.
(latitudes and longitudes linking the starting point(PIKINE) to arrival point(GUEDIAWAYE) that would trace the path.)

Answer (score 0):

Click on the point for which you want to know the LAT and LONG, right click and chose "whats here" It will show you the latitude and longitude. 
If you want to extract using a code, you need to get the google maps API.

Comment: https://www.google.sn/maps/dir/Pikine/Gu%C3%A9diawaye/@14.7672607,-17.4042385,15z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m13!4m12!1m5!1m1!1s0xec10ca2bb1e5ab1:0x783a4bf2d1a3408f!2m2!1d-17.3937536!2d14.7589446!1m5!1m1!1s0xec10c87916c2ddf:0x25307003a3de8a75!2m2!1d-17.3996674!2d14.7753661?hl=fr

Comment: thank you for the answer.Yes I can see the latitude and longitude by right click now I would like a script that would allow for all the different items from point of departure to destination.
Normally it is based on all the points to the drawn and how to get all the items automatically